# argv: Sanitizing wildcards

Tags: c, linux, shell, gcc, glob

I was working on an example in the K&R C book where it asks you to essentially build an RPN calculator that takes input through command line arguments. My solution essentially iterates through the given arguments and spits out the answer, but I noticed something:

If I were to give the multiplication character (an asterisk) `'*'` without single quotes, gcc assumes that to be a wildcard input, so my input of

```
$./rpn 5 10 *
```

gives me an output of

```
read 5
read 10
read rpn
read rpn.c
= 0
```

Wrapping the asterisk with single quotes remedies the issue

```
$./rpn 5 10 '*'
read 5
read 10
read *
= 50
```

My question is would there be a way to sanitize input so that my program does not require the asterisk to be wrapped in single quotes, or is this behavior caused by something more fundamental (e.g. Linux/POSIX/UNIX binary execution and argument handling)?

Comment: All to do with the shell; nothing to do with the C compiler at all.  To demonstrate, try writing a tiny program: `#include <unistd.h>` and `int main(void) { char *args[] = { "./rpn", "5", "10", "*", 0 }; execv(args[0], args); return -1; }`. The shell normally expands the `*`; this avoids using the shell so no expansion occurs.

Comment: GCC doesn't know anything. The shell is the one feeding the input to your program.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler @self I've tried this and it is as you've said; it executes and outputs the correct answer. As @IgnacioVazquez-Abrar stated below, it's caused by bash expanding the `*` wildcard glob into a list of all files in the current directory. I should certainly be more mindful of the shell.

Comment: It is a standard trap; the `*` is the only commonly used arithmetic operator that is also a shell metacharacter.  If you used parentheses with an infix calculator (by definition you don't use parentheses with an RPN calculator), then they'd get in your way too as they have a special meaning to the shell too.

Comment: In case you really want your Bash not to do pathname expansion, start it with `bash -f` or type `set -f` in a running Bash (and `set +f` to undo).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shell is expanding the glob before executing the program. You quote the glob not because of GCC, but because of the shell. If you don't want this behavior then use a shell that does not honor globs.

Comment: I see. This could be a very common cause of undefined behavior if one isn't too careful with what inputs a dev is programming for if they don't take the shell into account. I suppose there's a hidden lesson in this example, and that's to account for that often overlooked layer of execution.

Comment: It's not really overlooked, in my opinion. You just have to know your tools.

Comment: And it's not 'undefined behavior'. It's perfectly well defined; it's just not what you want here.

Comment: @duskwuff You're right. I guess a better word to use would be 'unintentional'.

Answer (score 0):

Give input as

```
$./rpn "5 10 *"
```

All argument in `""` and in program you will get all argument under `argv[1]` then parse that string by space separation.

By this way you do need to handle any wildcard/special character at special way.

Comment: Alternatively, you're treating all characters as needing special attention…and complicating the `rpn` program.

Comment: when ever any space come in any file names/path which is given by such Command line argumemt it creates problem in linux and windows so another way to handle such all things is treating all them as special

Comment: @Mr.32 I would usually agree with you if the scenario was different, however the exercise specifically called for the input to be processed as discrete command-line arguments.