# Passing Special Characters though Command Line Arguments Eclipse vs Visual Studio

Tags: c, eclipse, visual-studio

So I have this C code which gives me different output depending upon where I run it and how I run it. The code is

```
#include <stdio.h>    // needed to print to the command window screen
#include <stdlib.h>   // ASCII to integer conversion

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // check for a valid number of inputs.
    if (argc != 1 && argc != 7) {
        printf(
                "Incorrect arguments passed: It is either no arguments for default value (i.e: phase1.exe). ");
        printf(
                "or \"phase1 -r n -c n -v *\". n is number from 1-20.");
        // non-zero return values often indicate different types of failure/
        return -1;
    }

    if (argc != 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            printf("%s ", argv[i]);
            printf("\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the code on Visual Studio with cmd line argument as `-r 2 -c 3 -v *` The output is as following

```
-r
2
-c
3
-v
*
```

which is what I would expect. But now moving to Eclipse CDT

### The problem

If I launch the code in run mode with same command line argument I get this

```
Incorrect arguments passed: It is either no arguments for default value (i.e: phase1.exe).
```

Meaning Eclipse is somehow omitting the `*` character in the command line argument so the number of argument passed decreases from 7 to 6. **However**, if instead of using the run mode, if I use the Debug mode. The code doesn't give me error, but it doesn't give me the right answer either. The output I get from debug mode is this

```
-r 
2 
-c 
3 
-v
```

It doesn't print the star character. I checked the variable window, and it is there the whole time. But for some reason, eclipse doesn't print it. I am not sure whether this eclipse issue or visual studio being extra smart and eclipse doing exactly what I asked it do do.

Comment: [Its not the OS it is the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098588/argv-sanitizing-wildcards)

Comment: @Cody Correct me if I am wrong. So Eclipse honors the glob while the VS does not. Is there a way I can make eclipse not think of * as wild card? Also why the debug mode does not throw error similar to run mode?

Comment: I think I have found the issue of glob https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718873/the-issue-of-in-command-line-argument. Though I am not sure why debug and run mode behave differently.